# convert datetime to time

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object "2/17/2011 6:46:01 PM".I want to convert this object to 6:46 PM

Comment: Thats great. Where is your question? And please don't shout all the time...

Comment: What is the input? A string? A DateTime?

Comment: Please disable capslock.

Comment: How about marking your last question answered before you post a new one..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can format the object as

```
strdate = convert.todatetime(object);
strdate .tostring("hh:mm tt");
```

or

```
strdate.toshorttime();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
string myDateString = "2/17/2011 6:46:01 PM";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(myDateString);
string timeString = datetime.ToShortTimeString();

Console.WriteLine(timeString); // 6:46 PM
```

You can format the parsed datetime to a string in many other ways, but the `ToShortTimeString` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need just format?!

```
DateTime.Parse(obj.ToString()).ToString("h:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Globalization;
```

...

```
string dateString, format;
        format = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
        dateString = "2/17/2011 6:46:01 PM";
        DateTime result;
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

See here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If input is a string in first convert it to a dateTime by DateTime.parse method and then convet it to shortTimeString Or other
If input is DateTime convert it to shorttimeString in this form : input.toShortTimeString