# how to convert date time to only time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to convert datetime format to only time format.

data type - string

```
op- 5/31/2017 8:43:20 PM
req op - 8:43 (in 24 hours format)
```

code

```
TankDetailsModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
```

Comment: do you want it in string ?

Comment: Please show us the source code for TankDetailsModel, in particular the UpdatedTime property.

Comment: "convert datetime format to only time format.".... ehrm `.ToString("HH:mm");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TankDetailsModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString("HH:mm");
```

this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ToString ("HH:mm")

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this.

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    var x = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
string myDateString = "2/17/2011 6:46:01 PM";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(myDateString);
string timeString = datetime.ToShortTimeString();
Console.WriteLine(timeString);
```

Comment: check this link for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026346/convert-datetime-to-time